# Relation between two users and enforcing access control on that in buddypress/wordpress

Tags: wordpress, access-control, relationships, buddypress

How do I create relation between two users and enforce access control on that in buddypress/wordpress?

Comment: What kind of relationship?

Comment: relations like- Friend,close friend or family ( friend is already there, want to add some more relations)